# Odata service not fully return json in php Curl

Tags: php, odata

Thank you in advance
I tried to get odata service url using curl using following code

```
<?php
$url = "serviceurl/odata.srv/Users?$format=json&$expand=EmployeeDetails/ClientDetails/ClientConfigurationDetails,EmployeeDetails/ClientDetails/LogoDetails,SalutationTexts,UserConfigurationDetails";



$ch = curl_init($url); // such as http://example.com/example.xml
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_BASIC);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, "username:password");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
'Content-Type: application/json',
'Accept: application/json'));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);

$data = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);

echo $data;
```

only resulting the user details the expand details are not there but in postman and calling directly in browser its working fine getting all details

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give the url in single quotes like below

```
$url = 'serviceurl/odata.srv/Users?$format=json&$expand=EmployeeDetails/ClientDetails/ClientConfigurationDetails,EmployeeDetails/ClientDetails/LogoDetails,SalutationTexts,UserConfigurationDetails';
```

While using double quotes php will try to replace the $format and $expand variables which are actually odata parameters not php variables.

Hope this helps.

Comment: It was my mistake i forgot to special characters in the url